# Chemical equilibrium on phase diagram

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, equilibrium

I have doubts about whether chemical equilibrium is possible outside phase coexistence lines on phase diagrams.

I understand that on coexistence lines, chemical potentials of two phases are equal but what happens to chemical potentials outside coexistence lines?

Consider the phase diagram for $H_2 O$

[image]

In the water-steam coexistence line, water and steam are in chemical equilibrium $\mu_{steam}=\mu_{water}$. If we are in the water phase, then $\mu_{steam}>\mu_{water}$. In that phase, steam particles will spontaneously transform into water particles until there are no steam particles left but I am not sure how $\mu_{steam}$ and $\mu_{water}$ change during the condensation process. Will they both decrease until $\mu_{steam}=\mu_{water}$? If so, then this makes chemical equilibrium is possible outside coexistence lines?

Answer (score 1):

Outside the coexistence line, only one phase is present at equilibrium conditions. Therefore no chemical equilibrium between different phases is possible.

A possible way of describing such a situation in terms of equilibrium thermodynamics is the following.

We can think of two systems in a pure phase. Following the example, say liquid (L) and steam (S) water. In some way, we constrain each system to remain in its phase, even if it is not the real equilibrium phase at a given temperature and pressure. In practice, although with some limitations, this can be done by exploiting the possibility of metastable pure phases in experiments or by introducing some explicit constraint in a computer simulation. Therefore, we can speak about $\mu_L$ and $\mu_S$ as equilibrium properties of the pure phases even out of the coexistence line.

Thermodynamics says that if we have a compound system made by two subsystems constrained to be in two different phases at a given temperature and pressure, as soon as we release the constraint, the system will evolve spontaneously towards an equilibrium condition corresponding to the pure constrained phase of minimum chemical potential (Gibbs free energy per particle). Once the new unconstrained equilibrium is reached, only one phase will be present: the phase with the minimum chemical potential.

The only case where two phases will coexist at the final equilibrium condition is the case of coexistence ( $\mu_L=\mu_S$ ).

The previous description is the purely classical description of thermodynamic behavior. Let's remember that classical thermodynamics describes the equilibrium states and not the dynamic evolution between different equilibrium states. In the case of inhomogeneous systems, if we can justify a local thermodynamic condition, we are allowed to speak about the *local* values of the chemical potential. In such a case, we can better understand what is going on with the possible coexistence. That is the approach of nucleation theory, where we analyze the evolution of a local fluctuation of a pure system corresponding to the spontaneous appearance of a small region of the other phase. It turns out that outside the coexistence line, a fluctuation corresponding to a small macroscopic region of the phase with the highest chemical potential is unstable and quickly disappears. That is the only case where one can meaningfully speak about the unstable phase's chemical potential (an equilibrium property) in a dynamic process toward equilibrium.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to think about the chemical potential and chemical equilibrium:

- if the substance can exist at two or more *different states*, all at the same $T$ and $P$, then the most stable state is the one with the *lowest* chemical potential
- if the chemical potential is the same in more than one distinct states, then all of the these states can coexist with each other and each constitutes a phase
- when we say *chemical equilibrium* we mean that in a closed system under constant $T$ and $P$ all components are at the minimum chemical potential they can possible have
- *phase splitting* (or phase equilibrium) is a special case of chemical equilibrium and not the other way around; the fact that there is no phase splitting in the the stable phase region of the phase diagram does not mean that the we don't have chemical equilibrium in these regions –indeed we do, with only a single phase present

Answer (score 0):

The chemical potential is a state variable, so it's a function of that particular phase and its temperature and pressure.

Chemical potential minimization tells matter how to move, so if $\mu_\text{vapor}>\mu_\text{liquid}$, then the vapor will spontaneously condense into liquid.

For a large amount of vapor and a nearly constant temperature and pressure, this phase change could occur for a while at the interface without $\mu_\text{vapor}$ or $\mu_\text{liquid}$ changing. As the vapor depletes, however, or if the released latent heat doesn't dissipate away, or if the reaction alters the surrounding pressure, then $\mu_\text{vapor}$ or $\mu_\text{liquid}$ or both could very well change. [Le Chatelier's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier%27s_principle) tells us that this change will generally bring $\mu_\text{vapor}$ and $\mu_\text{liquid}$ closer together; in other words, Nature loves negative feedback.

Ultimately, $\mu_\text{vapor}$ and $\mu_\text{liquid}$ will be equal, and the process will stop. Alternatively, for phase changes between condensed phases, which carry a surface area penalty, complete melting or freezing could occur with $\mu_\text{liquid}$ and $\mu_\text{solid}$ never being equal, or the system could end up in a solid–liquid equilibrium where $\mu_\text{liquid}$ and $\mu_\text{solid}$ are equal.